Definition of étale cover
A morphism of schemes $f:X\to Y$ is said to be étale if it is flat and unramified, meaning that $f$ is locally of finite presentation, the induced map on stalks is flat and sends the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{Y, f(p)}$ to the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$, and $k(x)/k(y)$ is a separable algebraic extension. An étale cover is a collection of étale morphisms $\{X_i \to X\}$ which are jointly surjective.
I believe my definitions are correct. However, now I run into a problem with the following example, which is claimed to be an étale cover. Let $k$ be a field with $\mathrm{char}(k) \neq 2$, and $a \in k$ be non-zero. The family
$$i:\mathbb{A}^1-\{a\} \to \mathbb{A}^1$$
$$(-)^2:\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\} \to \mathbb{A}^1,$$
where $i$ is the inclusion and $(-)^2$ is the squaring map, is an étale cover. This is a typical example of a cover which is Nisnevich (if $a$ is a square in $k$) or isn't Nisnevich (if $a$ isn't a square in $k$). However, I am not understanding why this is always an étale cover unless my definitions are incorrect.
Edit: To clarify, I am asking why this family is an étale cover. This particular example is Example 3.41 in Antieau and Elmanto's "A primer for unstable motivic homotopy theory".

@KReiser I guess my concern is the following. the first map misses $a$, so the second map must hit it. But if $a$ isn't a square, then there are no solutions to $x^2=a$, and thus the second map doesn't hit $a$.

Where did you find that statement? Please give a precise reference. Maybe $k$ is algebraically closed in that context.

@categorically_stupid Are you asking why the given morphisms are étale, or are you asking why the given family is an étale cover?

@MartinBrandenburg This is example 3.41 in Antieau and Elmanto's "A primer for unstable motivic homotopy theory" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00929. It is also an example on the Wikipedia page for Nisnevich topology.

@ZhenLin I am asking why the family is an étale cover.

Right. I think KReiser was explaining why $({-})^2$ is étale, which I presume you have no complaint about. Your concern about surjectivity is misplaced. The scheme $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is not just $k$ with a generic point; it has closed points corresponding to every irreducible polynomial over $k$.

I have fixed the mistakes in the post. Please double check.

I was attempting to explain surjectivity, but there was an error in the post and I had also misread it slightly. Anyways, Martin Brandenburg has already covered the surjectivity in his answer below.

I assume you already know that the morphisms are étale. So what is missing is a proof that $i : \mathbb{A}^1 - \{a\} \to \mathbb{A}^1$ and $(-)^2 : \mathbb{A}^1 - \{0\} \to \mathbb{A}^1$ are jointly surjective.
Algebraically, this means that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq k[X]$ one of the following is true:

$\mathfrak{p} \neq (X-a)$,
$\mathfrak{p} = \{f \in k[X] : f(X^2) \in \mathfrak{q}\}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \neq (X)$

So we may assume right away that $\mathfrak{p} = (X - a)$. Since this is a maximal ideal and $\{f \in k[X] : f(X^2) \in \mathfrak{q}\}$ does not contain $1$, it is sufficient to find a prime $\mathfrak{q} \neq (X)$ such that $\{f \in k[X] : f(X^2) \in \mathfrak{q}\}$ contains $X-a$, that is, with $X^2 - a \in \mathfrak{q}$. The condition $\mathfrak{q} \neq (X)$ holds anyway because of $a \neq 0$.
Equivalently, we need to find an irreducible polynomial $g \in k[X]$ such that $g$ divides $X^2 - a$, because then we take $\mathfrak{q} := (g)$.
Well, the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $k$ does the job. It is either $X - \sqrt{a}$ if $a$ has a root in $k$, or $X^2 - a$ itself.
Notice that in the second case the field extension $k(\mathfrak{p}) \to k(\mathfrak{q})$ is given by $k \hookrightarrow k(\sqrt{a})$, which has degree $2$. So the cover is not Nisnevich.
